# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: invalid content was found starting with element 'ProcessDesc'. One of ProcessName expected

Tags: xml, jaxb, schema, xsd

I am validating my jaxb object through Validator class. Below is the code I am using to validate jaxb object. But While validating it I am getting this error.

```
jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj.getClass());
source = new JAXBSource(jc, obj);
Schema schema = schemaInjector.getSchema();
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(source);
```

**ERROR(SAXParseException): cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: invalid content was found starting with element 'ProcessDesc'. One of ProcessName expected**

I don't understand what I have done wrong in my xsd which is causing this error. The element defined in my xsd file is below for which I am getting an error.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:cc="http://www.ms.com/cm.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.ms.com/cm.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:complexType name="Process">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ProcessId" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element name="ProcessName" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="ProcessDesc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Please help me to solve this. Thank You.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The XML Schema code

```
<xs:complexType name="Process">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="ProcessId" type="xs:int" />
    <xs:element name="ProcessName" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="ProcessDesc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

describes some XML which ought to look like

```
<proc> <!-- of type Process -->
  <ProcessId>123</ProcessId>
  <ProcessName>procA</ProcessName>
  <ProcessDesc>A funny process</ProcessDesc> <!-- this could be omitted -->
<proc>
```

But your XML data looks like

```
<proc> <!-- of type Process -->
  <ProcessId>123</ProcessId>
  <ProcessDesc>A funny process</ProcessDesc>
  <!-- ... don't know what follows -->
```

If you don't care about the order of Id, Name, Desc you'll have to change the XML schema. Otherwise you'll have to fix the XML (which is easier).

If you think that "any order of elements" is a good idea, use:

```
<xs:complexType name="Process">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="ProcessId" type="xs:int" />
    <xs:element name="ProcessName" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="ProcessDesc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution saved my lot of time. Basically I wasn't getting process name element value in my xml. Thank you so much.

Comment: For me, it was just a typo. This answer helped to find out that. Thanks

Comment: Sorry guys if its a stupid question. I have inherited code. what is the location of this xml?

Comment: You must be more specific if you want answers. Which XML? Presumably it is on OP's computer.

Answer (score 13):

These kind of errors are due to one of the following reason

1. Element name is mistyped.
2. Element not described in the schema is trying to be used.
3. Elements are in an incorrect order.
4. Namespace definitions declared either in the root tag or a parent element doesn't match with the prefix (or no prefix) used in the element.
5. Java object has a null field required in XSD

Comment: Great explanation, in my case was an imperceptible extra char at tag name. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use a sequence you must keep the order of each element

Definition and Usage
The sequence element specifies that the child elements must appear in a sequence. Each child element can occur from 0 to any number of times.

see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple XSD validation error ... [w3c](http://gusto77.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/web-service-cxf-interceptor-replacing-request-data/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is **constraint violations** when you set a **field as required** and it's `NULL` in a record. Check your `XSD`'s `minOccurs` element property.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue fixed in ITR Utility software (as mentioned in [incomeTaxReturnUtilities](https://www.incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/downloads/incomeTaxReturnUtilities))

Some fields were filled mistakenly in this section:
[image: audit-report]

If filled we need to enter section code, date etc all details else left un-filled.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same issue and resolved it by adding the statement " maxOccurs="unbounded"" to the xsd bloc[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bunv.png)